# Translating cmp in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I'm new to assembly and ran accross the following ling:

```
cmp 0x2c(%esp),%esi
```

It's clearly trying to compare, but I don't know what 0x2c(%esp) is. I'm using GDB, so a command to access that value would be helpful. The next line sees if the two values are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is at&t syntax. You can switch gdb to intel syntax using `set disassembly-flavor intel` to get more readable code. You can examine the value using for example `x/d $esp+0x2c`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with your assembler's syntax, but I'd gather it is comparing the contents of register `ESI` with the contents of the memory location at (stack pointer + 2C hex)